# is there any way to lock a row temporarily

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am using sql server with my VB.NET application where in multiple instance of the application is run from different server (CITRIX). I am sorting and picking up one individual Row for processing and immediately marking that row as picked in a column so that other instance doesn't pick up the same row and waste time. The issue is, in between picking up the row and updating as picked, another instance of the application is picking up the row. I have been suggested for using with DB Lock but the concept is not that much clear to me like whether it will solve my problem, whether I need admin right to use it (I do not have admin right in client DB) etc. Below is the code snippet I have used.

```vb
Dim MyConnection As SqlConnection
Try
MyConnection = New SqlConnection(connString)
MyConnection.Open()
Dim tableName As String = myTableName
Dim sqlQuery As String = "Select Top 1 * from " + tableName + " where "<some condition>
Dim MyCommand As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlQuery, MyConnection)
Dim DS as DataSet = New DataSet
MyCommand.Fill(DS, tableName)
If DS.Tables(0).Rows.Count >= 1 Then
    sqlQuery = "UPDATE " + tableName + " SET Fld = @fld  where Cond1= '" + DS.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Cond1").ToString + "'"
    Dim cmd As New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sqlQuery)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@fld", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "Picked" 
    Try
        cmd.Connection = MyConnection
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End If
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.ToString)
Finally
    MyConnection.Close()
End Try
```

I want it to make in such way that if an instance picks up a row, until it finishes updating the row, the row will not be visible to other instance with same query on the table, but other instance will continue to work with the other rows at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Two options I see:

- Change your `SELECT` and `UPDATE` queries to a single `UPDATE` query. I didn't see where your `SELECT` was buying you anything.
- If the `SELECT` is truly needed, then use a stored procedure on the database to handle the `SELECT` and the `UPDATE` on the database server side. You can lock the row during the transaction. See: [Transaction Locking and Row Versioning Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-2017)

Note that in general you should try to move your database queries to stored procedures. Not only does this reduce the amount of network traffic moving datasets back and forth, it increases the reliability, separates your database code from the UI, allows updates to the procedures without having to push new versions of the client application out and also avoids SQL injection.

Comment: I am using different SELECT and UPDATE because I need some data from that row to do some stuff, which I will not be able to identify after updating "Picked" as other instances are also marking "Picked" to their rows of data at the same time.

Comment: Do I need admin right to create stored procedure, asking because client has not provided me admin access to their database, I can only use UPDATE query, nothing else like creating new table etc. is allowed.

Comment: You would need rights to the schema that you are generating the SP in. The client could create a new schema for you (that is, other than `dbo.` then you could CREATE the SP's you need and the client admin could copy them to `dbo` after review. This is superior to granting you broad `UPDATE` access, since your code _could_ do something like `UPDATE table SET col1 = NULL, set col2 = NULL, etc`. But by using SPs the client would be able to assure than nothing bad is happening.